Finding Side Lengths BC and AC in a Triangle with an Incircle and Specific Geometric Properties
I'm working on a problem that involves a triangle ( ABC ) with an incircle ( O ) tangent to ( AB ), ( BC ), and ( CA ) at points ( D ), ( E ), and ( F ) respectively. Additionally, ( $\angle DEF$ ) is given as ( $45^\circ$ ). Here are the details and specific questions:

( AB = 4 ) units and ( AG = 2 ) units, where ( G ) is a point on ( AC ), such that ( BG ) is an extension of ( BO ) and intersects ( AC ) at ( G ).
I am tasked with finding the lengths of sides ( BC ) and ( AC ).

Given that ( AG = 2 ), and considering ( AB = 4 ), I initially thought ( BG = 2 ) since ( BG ) is the extension of ( BO ). However, I am unsure how to proceed from here, particularly in using ( $\angle DEF = 45^\circ$ ) to find the side lengths.
Challenges and Importance:
This problem has stumped me because I understand that incircles and their properties usually provide clear pathways in geometric constructions, but I am unable to apply them directly here. The triangle’s side ( BC ) and ( AC ) remain elusive due to the complex nature of the setup.
Question:
Can anyone suggest methods or theorems that could help calculate ( BC ) and ( AC ) in this configuration? I'm particularly interested in how ( $\angle DEF = 45^\circ$ ) might help in determining these lengths.
Context:
This problem is part of a larger study on the properties of triangles with incircles, which has applications in both theoretical geometry and practical architectural design. Understanding these properties can enhance the design of aesthetically pleasing and structurally sound constructions.


Welcome to Math.SE! ... Are you familiar with the Inscribed Angle Theorem?

Since $\angle DEF = 45, \angle DOF = 90$. Since $\angle ODA = OFA = 90, \angle BAC = 90$. Thus the inradius is the length of the square in right angle triangle BAG. I'm sure there are many ways to continue from here but the one that occurred to me first was to coord bash with A being (0, 0), G being (0, 2) and B being (4, 0). Solving for $y=x$ and $\frac{x}{4}+\frac{y}{2}=1$ gives O to be $(\frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{3})$ so the radius length is $\frac{4}{3}$.
For finding lengths angle bisector theorem can be used which gives $\frac{BA}{BG} = 2 = \frac{BC}{BG}$, and since $\angle BAC = 90$ we have $(GC + 2)^2 + 4^2 = BC^2$, and combining this with the previous result will give the side lengths. This gives $BG = \frac{10}{3}, BC = \frac{20}{3}$.
Also, consider using $I$ for the incentre as that is what is typically done, $O$ is usually used for the circumcentre.


Another approach:
$\angle EFD=45^o\Rightarrow \angle EOD=90$
$\triangle GEO\sim \triangle GAB$
$\frac{EG}{EO}=\frac{GA}{AB}=\frac 24=\frac 12$
$AG=(EA=EO)+EG \Rightarrow \frac {AG}{EO}=1+(\frac{EG}{EO}=\frac 12)=\frac 32$
$\frac 2{EO}=\frac 32\Rightarrow EO=AD=\frac 43$
$CE=CF$
$BF=DB=4-\frac 43=\frac 83$
Bisector theorem:
$\frac{AD+DB}{BF+FC}=\frac{AG}{GC}$
Puting values we get:
$4 CG=\frac{16}3+2FC$
$CG=FC-EG=FC-\frac 23$
These two relations give $FC=4$. So we have:
$AC=CE+ EA=4+\frac 43=\frac{16}3$
$BF=BD=\frac 43$
$BC=CF+FB=4+\frac83=\frac{20}3$
